# Connect from Mac OS X to Windows 7 Desktop

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am trying to connect from my MacBook to my Windows 7 machine **within my own network** - if it will work from outside my network that's a plus but no need to have.

My Windows 7 machine is freshly installed with Windows 7 Home Premium. It runs the built-in firewall with no settings changed so far as well as Microsoft Security Essentials.

So far I tried CoRD and Microsofts Remote Desktop Connections to connect from my Mac to my Windows machine without any success.

I did try and disabled the firewall on my Windows machine but could not connect either. The reason I did this was to check wether there is a Windows firewall setting preventing me from connecting.
On top of that I manually started the *Remote Desktop Services* and *Remote Desktop Configuration* within *services.msc*.

Is there anything else I have to enable for a remote desktop connection?

Could there be any router setting I have to tweak? Since I do not want to connect from outside my own network I thought I don't have to do any port forwarding.

The error messages I retrieve are all connection timeouts.
I can however ping the hostname and/or IP address.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

jrn

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not able to establish a remote desktop connection with Windows 7 Home Premium. There seems to be a hack which one can apply through patching the termsrv.dll.

Answer (score 0):

The Home Premium version does not have the Terminal Services server enabled, so you can't use RDP to connect to the machine. You need at least Professional version of Windows to have that feature enabled (or use the hack mentioned in the other answer - YMMV)